# How to see optimized c++ code?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, compiler-optimization

Is it possible to see optimized C++ code by compiler in training reasons? Interesting for **clang** and **g++**. For example, I expect to see files like:

- main.cpp
- main.cpp.optimized

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but generally compilers don't optimise at the source level - they tend to do optimisation at lower levels, typically using some sort of intermediate representation and then again when performing code generation.

Comment: `g++ -fdump-tree-optimized` dumps an intermediate file in a C-like language which has most high-level optimizations already performed.

Comment: I want to see the code after compiler's optimization step: after preprocessing and optimizations. I am interested in high-level source code optimizations which are done by the compiler. For example, simple volatile optimization. But if @PaulR is right then it is not possible.

Comment: `clang++ -O2 -S -emit-llvm` .. but I don't think it is what you expect